# How can I add a title for the module settings in DotNetNuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

For a custom module developed in DotNetNuke (05.01.01) I have added additional settings on the settings page were I have the "Module Settings" and "Page Settings" but I couldn't figure out how to add a title to this group of settings.

How can I add the title?

Please find attached a screen grab that shows exactly where I need the title:

[image: screenshot with missing title highlighted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings control need to define the title in its local resources file (probably App_LocalResources/Settings.ascx.resx), with the key `ControlTitle_settings.Text`